# vb.net textfile ReadLine Loops

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file that looks like the below format. I am trying to create a data table out of the format.  I have tried a few different things to format it correctly however I am having an issue with ReadLine

```
Dim SectionLineONE as string
Dim NextSectionLine As String

 srReader = File.OpenText(MyFile)

             Dim SectionLineONE As String
    Do
        SectionLineONE = srReader.ReadLine()

           If SectionLineONE Is Nothing Then Exit Do
           If SectionLineONE.Contains("1.0") Then

              Dim NextSectionLine As String
              Do

                  NextSectionLine = srReader.ReadLine()

                  If NextSectionLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                  If NextSectionLine.Contains("1.1") Then

                      Dim NextSectionLine3 As String
                      Do

                          NextSectionLine3 = srReader.ReadLine()

                          If NextSectionLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                        If NextSectionLine.Contains("1.1.1") Then

                            Dim NextSectionLine4 As String
                            Do

                                NextSectionLine4 = srReader.ReadLine()

                                If NextSectionLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                                If NextSectionLine.Contains("1.1.1.1") Then

                                    'I want the program to go to the first do loop now and check 2.0, 2.1 etc



                                End If
                            Loop


                        End If
                    Loop

                End If

            Loop
        End If
    Loop





   Text File

1.0
Section 1 Title:
1.1
Section Title 
1.1.1
Section Title
1.1.1.1
Section  Title
```

Comment: How is this different than [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40897137/1070452) ???

Comment: @Plutonix ...and we can't close it as a dup.

Comment: It different because I added how I get to 1.1.1.1. Once the program read 1.1.1.1 how can i get it to my first do loop. Never answered

Comment: `Never answered ` its only been an hour, grasshopper.  @LarsTech we *can*  I was legitimately curious if there was some reason

Comment: Should I not be using Do loops like I am or not multiple readlines?

Comment: Sorry the smart guys like you never come back to it :)

Comment: @Plutonix Can't close it as a dupe due to:  "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"

Comment: Would prefer if i delete it?

Comment: If you had edited the original it would have gotten 'bumped' on the NEW page.  @LarsTech - thats not supposed to apply when it is the same user

Comment: @Plutonix Not the same user.  :-)

Comment: The other one has 3 close votes on it...likely due to the vague `I am having an issue with ReadLine`

Comment: Ahhh, a sock puppet! Sorry, missed that

Comment: I told you what I would do - use System.Version to detect the header lines, then contains to detect children,  You are still using string literals which is not maintainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this assuming the file looks like that it looks like that all the time: no extra comment lines, 1 piece of data,  and in order:

```
Dim ver As New System.Version

Dim data = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\SockpuppetData.txt")
Dim verData As New Dictionary(Of Version, String)

Dim ndx As Int32 = 0
Do Until ndx >= data.Count - 1
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(data(ndx)) = False Then
        If System.Version.TryParse(data(ndx), ver) Then
            ndx += 1
            verData.Add(ver, data(ndx))
        End If
    End If
    ndx += 1
Loop

' debug
For Each kvp In verData
    Console.WriteLine("v: {0} t:{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
Next
```

At the end you will have a Dictionary of version objects and the related text.  If there is more than one line of text, use `Dictionary(Of Version, String())`.  If they are not in order, use a `List(Of KeyValuePair(of Version, String))` and sort it afterwards.

Then it is just a matter of gluing them together.  Results:

> v: 1.0 t:Section 1 Title:
>   v: 1.1 t:Section Title
>   v: 1.1.1 t:Section Title
>   v: 1.1.1.1 t:Section  Title
>   v: 2.0 t:Section Title:
>   v: 2.1 t:Section Title
>   v: 2.1.1 t:Section Title
>   v: 2.1.1.1 t:Section Title

Rather than trying to go from start to finish in one loop/step, collect the data into something you can work with: sort, count, compare etc. The `Version` type will allow you to compare and determine things.  Then create your output from that.

The sample data seems a bit homogeneous.  For instance there is nothing like a `1.2` which would mess up the titles.  The sets are also the same size between 1.x and 2.x which allows those titles to line up by accident. If they were in a list you could count the depth to know how many `Subs` to append.